# ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity. Problem with Astropy

Tags: python, astropy

I'm currently working on a program that needs the package Astropy in order to work. However, since a few weeks, I can't manage to make `sidereal_time` work. Even with the easiest examples obtained from the docs, like this one:

```
from astropy.time import Time
t = Time('2006-01-15 21:24:37.5', scale='utc')
t.sidereal_time('mean', 'greenwich')
```

I keep obtaining the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\9pabl\Desktop\astro.py", line 3, in <module>
    t.sidereal_time('mean', 'greenwich')
  File "C:\Users\9pabl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\astropy\time\core.py", line 1150, in sidereal_time
    gst = self._erfa_sidereal_time(available_models[model.upper()])
  File "C:\Users\9pabl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\astropy\time\core.py", line 1165, in _erfa_sidereal_time
    for scale in model['scales']
  File "C:\Users\9pabl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\astropy\time\core.py", line 1166, in <listcomp>
    for jd_part in ('jd1', 'jd2_filled')]
  File "C:\Users\9pabl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\astropy\time\core.py", line 1528, in __getattr__
    tm._set_scale(attr)
  File "C:\Users\9pabl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\astropy\time\core.py", line 718, in _set_scale
    args.append(get_dt(jd1, jd2))
  File "C:\Users\9pabl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\astropy\time\core.py", line 1643, in _get_delta_ut1_utc
    iers_table = IERS_Auto.open()
  File "C:\Users\9pabl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\astropy\utils\iers\iers.py", line 660, in open
    cls.iers_table = cls.read(file=filename)
  File "C:\Users\9pabl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\astropy\utils\iers\iers.py", line 507, in read
    table = cls._combine_a_b_columns(iers_a)
  File "C:\Users\9pabl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\astropy\utils\iers\iers.py", line 470, in _combine_a_b_columns
    table.meta['predictive_index'] = np.min(np.flatnonzero(is_predictive))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in amin
  File "C:\Users\9pabl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2746, in amin
    keepdims=keepdims, initial=initial, where=where)
  File "C:\Users\9pabl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 90, in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

This is seemingly exclusive of my computer since I tried running it in another one and it works fine. I've also tried to reinstall python, but doesn't work.

Comment: This is little more than a shot in the dark but does it work if you add location to your `t=Time()`  call?  Like so: `Time('2006-01-15 21:24:37.5', scale='utc', location=('120d', '45d'))`

Comment: No, it doesn't have any effect. Location is an optional parameter. It's very strange that the error shows.

Comment: When you run this do you have a network connection and does it try to download the IERS data?  Something like "Downloading https://maia.usno.navy.mil/ser7/finals2000A.all".  Also try `from astropy.utils.data import clear_download_cache; clear_download_cache()`.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the answer! `from astropy.utils.data import clear_download_cache; clear_download_cache()` worked fine. Problem solved.